# Programmatically launch registered viewer and wait for exit

Tags: iphone, ios4

Within my sandbox, I have PDFs, DOCs, XLSs, etc. How do I launch the native viewer for the file *and* wait for the viewer to exit?

In the Microsoft would, I would `ShellExectue` or `CreateProcess/WaitForSingleObject`. In Unix, I would `fork/exec/wait`. But I can't seem to locate the information for Apple's gear.

How does one programmatically launch registered viewer and wait for exit?

Comment: What do you mean by "launch the native viewer for the file"?  Are you using `UIDocumentInteractionController`?

Comment: I imgine there is an App for PDF files. I would like to shell out to the application which handles PDFs. Once the user is finished with the PDF, I need to regain control.

I'm not asking to gain control at an arbitrary point - I only need control once the user finished with the document. Considering I launched the application viewer, I hope that I'm allowed to get processing time after the viewer closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the file into a `UIWebView`, but you can’t launch another application and then wait for it to close.

Comment: Let me rephrase - suppose a user dropped a PDF in my application's sandbox on his/her desktop, and then used iTunes to sync it. The PDF is on a device in my application's sandbox. I want my application to (1) display it, and (2) edit it (if possible). I want to use the native application to do so. Native application meaning the application which has registered the file type. Is it possible?

Comment: @noloader: You can launch a file in another app, but doing so switches away from your app; the user will have to re-launch it to get back to it.